# Font ID for Fitbit Aria2's display?

Tags: font-identification

I'm looking for this font used in one Smart scale (Aria2).

I'd like to create a small display which displays my weight but with the same font.

I tried searching for it with both "whatfontis.com" and "whatthefont", but I was unsuccessful.

Here is a sampled image from the scale:

[image]

To see more, here is a <50s video from the weighting process where some more characters are being displayed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eXorUsIxp04

Closest font was "FF SubMono Std SubMono Condensed Dry":

[image]

It's pretty close, but `8` on the original image has a bigger bottom circle than this. Also `5` on the original has it's stomach curving upwards while on this one it starts horizontally:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The glyphs resemble New Letter Gothic (by ParaType) except pixelated due the low display resolution. This is a capture of few glyphs from ParaType's page:

[image]

I guess you will not find an exact match. The manufacturing costs of mass produced devices must be minimized. The font must be an optimized bitmap font just for that display and wanted look. The letter forms may well resemble some known font in such creation, but as a manufacturing material of the scale the custom bitmap font is controlled by the scale manufacturer, no need to worry licensing nor royalties. And no need to include any general font rendering software which would be a monster in systems which should be as simple as possible.

Comment: Perfect, that is enough for me to accept, as it's close enough to it.